# git - how to get a specific file from a remote repository

Tags: git

In my remote repo, I have multiple versions of a file that were all added and committed to the repository.

**git log** confirms that I have 4 versions. What i don't know how to do is to get a specific version from the remote repo  down to my local directory.

Both my local directory and remote repo, for now, reside on my computer. This is because it is a new installation and we are trying to figure out how GIT works.

Comment: Try `git checkout <commit hash> -- <file path>`

Comment: The documentation will be your best friend while learning git. Have fun! https://git-scm.com/docs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `git pull origin master`, you should have all the commits/versions in the local repo as the master branch of the remote repo.

If you do not want all the changes, you can get a specific commit from the remote repo by doing `git fetch origin SHA1-commit:refs/remotes/origin/foo-commit`

If you only want a specific file, you could do -

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file
```

This would download all the changes from the remote repo, but would only apply the changes for the specific path.

Hope this helps!